# Use strings for object names in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I got a user form with six checkboxes, named `chk1`, `chk2`, ..., `chk6`, which i need to go through and list the marked ones. I would like them to be listed right after each other, such that if there are four marked boxes, the caption of those boxes will be listed in `A1:A4` (even if it is not the four first boxes which are marked).

I have tried this code:

```
Dim i As Integer, n, As Integer
  n = 0
  For i = 1 To 6
    strChkName = "chk" & i
    If strChkName.Value Then
    Cells(1+n, 2) = strChkName.Caption
    n = n + 1
  End If
Next i
```

This however, does not work. Likely because of the combination of a string and the `.Value` thing.  I cannot seem to find anything regarding this. Is it even possible to do?

Comment: ...controls("name")...

Comment: more to the point `If Controls("chk" & i).Value Then`

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using comments from Nathan and Scott, I managed to solve the issue using the [Controls()](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/controls-collection.html) function in VBA. Used in my code, it looks like this:

```
Dim i As Integer, n, As Integer
  n = 0
  For i = 1 To 
    If Controls("chk" & i).Value Then
      Cells(1+n, 2) = Controls("chk" & i).Caption
      n = n + 1
    End If
Next i
```